# como resolvo esse exercico em c/c++

Tags: c, c++

no final eu ainda preciso printar quais lojas estão apresentando um preço dentro da media, alguem me ajuda;

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
struct difsites{
    double preco;
    char loja[50];
    char site[50];
};
int main(){
    int i,j;
    double soma, media;
    struct difsites MP;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        printf("Insira o nome da loja: ");
        scanf(" %50[^\n]s", &MP.loja);
        printf("Insira a URL: ");
        scanf(" %50[^\n]s", &MP.site);
        printf("Insira o valor do computador: ");
        scanf(" %lf", &MP.preco);
        soma+=MP.preco;
        media=soma/6.0;
    }
    printf("Preco medio: R$%.2lf\n",media);
}
```

Comment: Se você selecionar o código e apertar `ctrl+k`, ele ficará formatado bonitinho como está agora. Isso facilita a leitura

Comment: Para resolver esse problema, melhor começar armazenando diversas "`difsites`" para poder acessá-las depois. Você só vai ler elas uma vez, só pode tirar a média depois de ler todas elas e, no final, você precisa comparar cada "`difsites`" com a média. Isso é um bom indicativo de que necessita armazená-las para acessar posteriormente

Comment: Porquê a tag c++ ? Você não está a usar nada no programa que seja de c++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro erro no seu código está na variavel "soma", devemos inicializar ela como 0 se vamos incrementar a partir dela, por causa do lixo de memoria.

```
double soma = 0, media;
```

Para você armazenar as lojas, recomendo criar um vetor de estruturas. Ficando assim

```
struct difsites MP[6];
```

O segundo erro está na hora de calcular a media, você só irá calcular a media quando o ciclo for estiver acabado.

```
 for(i=0;i<6;i++){  //Le cada loja do vetor, começando da posicao 0 até 5
        printf("Insira o nome da loja: ");
        scanf(" %50[^\n]s", &MP[i].loja);
        printf("Insira a URL: ");
        scanf(" %50[^\n]s", &MP[i].site);
        printf("Insira o valor do computador: ");
        scanf(" %lf", &MP[i].preco);

        soma = soma + MP[i].preco; //Soma todos os preços das lojas
    }

    media = soma/6.0;
```

Depois para verificar se a loja está dentro da média é só fazer um ciclo for novamente com uma condição se menor que media, exibir o preço.

```
printf("Media do preco = %lf\n",media);
    for(i=0; i <6; i++){
        if(MP[i].preco <= media){
            printf("Loja %s | Preco =  R$%.2lf\n",MP[i].loja,MP[i].preco);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Acho que de tudo que o código original me incomodava, você só não tirou o número mágico. Então parabéns, eu sou muito chato e você atendeu a todas as minhas chatices =D

Comment: Kkkkkkk valeu cara, acabei não tirando o número mágico para tentar deixar o código mais parecido com o original.